# How do I fade in and out in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I understand there is a module built in FFmpeg which allows you to fade your clips in and out, however, no one really explains how to use the module with your own input. How do I simply fade both the audio and video in and out without re-encoding? (If that's possible)

Answer (score 5):

Fading **in** is no problem, because you start from the timestamp `0` (or from other known timestamp or frame number), e.g. use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fade=in:0:d=5 -af afade=in:0:d=5 output.mp4
```

for 5-second fading in from the start of your clip.

Ignore the error

> ```
> Only '-vf fade=in:0:d=5' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
> ```

— see the [answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/28215/18155) of the question [FFmpeg read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/28214/18155).

---

To fade **out**, you have to provide either

- the start position (the default parameter), i.e.

  - the start *frame* (`s=`) for video, or
  - the start *sample* (`ss=`) for audio,

  or
- the start *time* (`st=`) (this is the same parameter name for both audio and video)

of the fade out.

Let's use the second option - the start *time* of fading out.

First, figure out the total duration of video or audio (you may find it with FFprobe), then subtract the desired fade-out length from the length of the video.

For example, if you have a 10-minute video (= 600 seconds) and desire a 5-second fade out, you obtain `600 - 5 = 595`.

Add filters for fading out to the previous command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fade=in:0:d=5,fade=out:st=595:d=5 -af afade=in:0:d=5,afade=out:st=595:d=5 output.mp4
```

---

*Notes:*

1. Filtering always require re-encoding.
2. As `in` and `0` are defaults, you may shorten the command to

   ```
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fade=d=5,fade=out:st=595:d=5 -af afade=d=5,afade=out:st=595:d=5 output.mp4
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As the topic asks for ffmpeg in general, an additional info to the answer of MarianD if you have only audio; there are no frames, so you have to use the start time option and for that you have to use key/value pairs (at least for fading out):

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -af afade=in:st=0:d=5,afade=out:st=595:d=5 output.m4a
```

Comment: I by mistake rejected your edit of my answer, in spite that your proposal was correct. Please excuse me and repeat your edit (there is no way for me how to approve it if I already rejected it). Then I may approve it.

Comment: @MarianD, sorry, I remember it was only a small formatting change, but I don't remember it ... and I don't see it in the history ...

Comment: It was almost at the end, in the Note 2: `afade=out=595:5`. You corrected the second `=` into `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do fade out/in without reencoding.

Comment: Ah damn, how would I do with re-encoding?

Comment: @Mint Incorrect.

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica Yeah sorry, thanks for calling me out. idk what I was thinking that day. It's totally possible to fade in/out when you re-encode. (deleted my old comment)